# Is btSphereShape cheaper for calculations than btBoxShape?

Tags: bulletphysics, bullet

Always thought sphere is the cheapest collision primitive but it looks like Bullet creates a convex body for the sphere, don't it? So is the btSphereShape actually cheaper than the btBoxShape for collision computations or much more expensive?

Comment: What make you think "Bullet creates a convex body for the sphere"?

Comment: Inheritance from btConvexInternalShape. I didn't check for sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not a complete answer.  (A complete one should do a profile test.)*

From [the official wiki](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Collision_Shapes), they are not so different in performance
(both shape are grouped in to the same tier - **Primitives**) :-

> Using convex collision shapes such as convex hulls and primitives such
>   as a sphere, box and cylinder makes the collision algorithms much more
>   simple and efficient.

In the same page, it implies that Sphere is the fastest shape :-

> **btSphereShape :**  A very fast and simple shape.
>   **btBoxShape :**
>       A cuboid shape, the length in each dimension can be chosen arbitrarily.

### **Response to each mini questions**

> **OP:** btSphereShape actually cheaper .... , (because it is inherited) from btConvexInternalShape.

Yes, but the class hierchy is not the reason.
Both [sphere](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtSphereShape.html) and [box](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtBoxShape.html) are inherited from the `btConvexInternalShape`.
Sphere are just easy to calculate.

> **OP:** ... Bullet creates a convex body for the sphere ... (so) the btSphereShape actually cheaper

Primitive shape uses special highly-customized algorithm, so it is **cheaper** than general convex.    For an evidence, see [btSphereSphereCollisionAlgorithm](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btSphereSphereCollisionAlgorithm_8cpp_source.html) (cheap) vs [btConvexConvexAlgorithm](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btConvexConvexAlgorithm_8cpp_source.html) (expensive) .

### General guide

In practice, you should select the one that match your need. (except your application is really physics-intensive)

- As I browse the forum for a long time, there are no one mention/complain about difference in performance of **Box** vs **Sphere**.
- I have also used both of them for a few years and see no difference in practice.

You may be also interested in [collision-shape algorithm](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) (a popular collision detection website).
I believe Bullet use one of such algorithms.